# Ionic Native Google Map Geolocation watchposition is not working

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am using @ionic-native/geolocation to track the user's position.

```
startTracking() {

console.log("startTracking");

this.positionSubscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition()
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("subscription");
    console.log(data.coords.latitude);
    console.log(data.coords.longitude);
  });

 }
```

But when I change the position, nothing happened.
What's wrong? I am trying on android emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.
I used cordova-plugin-geolocation. But it is not working well on android.
It shows error
'getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.'
After spending much time to resolve this issue, I finally got answer.
Don't use this plugin.
Instead use this plugin. @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
This plugin is working well.
Hope this helps somebody who has same problem with me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this package and it works very well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/geolocation

This API is based on the W3C Geolocation API Specification, and only executes on devices that don't already provide an implementation.

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
   <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
</edit-config>
```